# Plug-in “org.codecover.eclipse” was unable to instantiate class “org.codecover.eclipse.junit.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate”

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage, junit4

I’m using CodeCover for Code Coverage. My Problem is when i run a test case as “CodeCover Measurement For JUnit” this message appears:

Plug-in “org.codecover.eclipse” was unable to instantiate class “org.codecover.eclipse.junit.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate”.

I’m using:
- Win 7 64
- Eclipse Neon with Java 8
- JUnit 4
- CodeCover 1.0.1.2

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could use Eclipse Kepler, as codeCover works fine with Kepler and has not been updated for neon.[Same question has been asked on sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/p/codecover/discussion/738682/thread/d9908fcf/?limit=25)